# Word to PDf converted PDF is having error -access denied error

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, itext

[image]After converting MS word document to PDF. If i send the same path of converted word to pdf. i.e PDF . while  file extracting i will get a error of access denied while publishing the website in server.It works in Local machine. Is there anything i left in code or is there anything i need to install .

```
 public string WordtoPdf_Input(string wordFileName_input)
    {

        try
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord_input = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object _MissingValue_ip = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            //filename_doc = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(LblFleip.Text);
            //wordFileName = LblFleip.Text;
            string pdfFileName = string.Empty;
            appWord_input.Visible = false;
            appWord_input.ScreenUpdating = false;

            // Cast as Object for word Open method
            object filename = (object)wordFileName_input;

            // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = appWord_input.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip);
            doc.Activate();

            InputFilename = pdfFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(wordFileName_input, ".pdf");
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

            //All is well until here, Save thinks the excelfile is readonly
            object tmpName = Path.GetTempFileName();

            File.Delete(tmpName.ToString());

            // Save document into PDF Format
            doc.SaveAs(ref tmpName,
             ref fileFormat, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip,
             ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip);

            // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
            // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
            // correct Close method.    

            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip);
            doc = null;

            // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
            // the correct Quit method.
            ((_Application)appWord_input).Quit(ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip, ref _MissingValue_ip);
            appWord_input = null;


            File.Delete(InputFilename.ToString());

            File.Move(tmpName.ToString(), InputFilename.ToString());
            //File.Move(tmpName,InputFilename.ToString())
            filePath_input = InputFilename.ToString();


            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();  // force final cleanup!
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        return filePath_input;
    }

Public void PDFnumofPagecount()
{
 LblFleip.Text = filePath_input;





                PdfReader readerPages_ip = new PdfReader(LblFleip.Text);
  NumberofPages_ip = readerPages_ip.NumberOfPages;
                txtbNumberofPages_ip.Text = NumberofPages_ip.ToString();
                readerPages_ip.Close();

}

i have used itextsharp for reading pages and extraction of PDF
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of the user (to ensure they have the required read/write) on the machine where it's giving the error?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. I upvoted it, because it was a good counter-question (but maybe it should have been added as a comment). I'm pretty sure the "access denied" warning is related to permissions. Either the file is locked, or the webserver runs as a user that has no access to the file.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. :)
I wanted to comment, but couldn't due to not having enough reputation! So, had to do it as an answer...

Comment: i had changed the server.with same permission now its working fine. same permission in one more server it is not working.